# Convert list of jsonNode objects to another class, but add a new parent field

Tags: java

I am very new to java and I hope my question is not too stupid and has enough info for you guys to help me out.
I have a list of jsonNodes, each of them is in the following format:

```
{"field1":value1, "field2":value2, "field3":value3, "notneeded1":value4, "notneeded2":value5}
```

I am currently using a class like the following and converting it to list

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class customClass:
    String field1;
    String field2;
    String field3;
Using TypeReference to convert the list of jsonNode to list of this class...
```

What I want to do is add a few of these fields within an another field

```
{"parentfield":{"field1":value1, "field2":value2}, "field3":value3}
```

How do I do this using this class?

Answer (score 0):

AFIU you want this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class CustomClass {
    public String field1;
    public String field2;
    public String field3;
    public CustomClass2 parentfield;

}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class CustomClass2 {
    public String field1;
    public String field2;
}
```

Then depends on your code, to set the values of the fields in an object of CustomClass2 with fields from an object of CustomClass.